# The system cannot find the path specified: Error while starting zookeeper(Apache Kafka)

Tags: java, path, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am getting the below error while starting Zookeeper server in the command prompt:
The system cannot find the path specified.
I am using Windows 8 OS, Kafka 2.12 and Java 8 JDK.

I have checked on the below:

1. Set `JAVA_HOME` to `JDK` bin folder.
2. Set the `PATH` environment variable correctly using `JAVA_HOME` as the relevant path.
3. Set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable correctly using `JAVA_HOME` as the relevant path.
4. Used shortened path in windows to avoid using spaces:
   Ex: C:\Progra~1 instead of C:\Program Files
5. Checked on the below commands in the command prompt:

   `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

   `echo %PATH%`

   `echo %CLASSPATH%`

   `where java`

   `java -version`

   `java -d64 -version`

   `javac -version`

All of them gave me the specified path. However it didn't resolved my issue.

Comment: show the command for starting zookeeper server

Comment: bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties

Please note that the issue stands resolved now.

Answer (score 4):

**I think JAVA_HOME should keep till JDK path not JDK\bin.**

Comment: In case you keep JAVA_HOME until JDK path then you ought to mention \bin explicitly in the PATH and CLASSPATH environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue:
My java home set was

```
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin
```

Then i did the  following change:

1)changed the jdk location to C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin as earlier location was containing spaces between Program and Files.

2)Also i need to change the kafka-run-class.bat file from

```
   IF ["%JAVA_HOME%"] EQU [""] (
set JAVA=java
    ) ELSE (
set JAVA="%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java"
```

)
to

```
    IF ["%JAVA_HOME%"] EQU [""] (
set JAVA=java
    ) ELSE (
set JAVA="%JAVA_HOME%/java"
```

)
.
As my java home already contains /bin suffix.So either remove the bin suffix from your java home or modify the kafka-run-class.

But still  i was getting same error when running from the command prompt.Then i closed the cmd and again opened the new command prompt and run the following command and it run successfully.

```
    .\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Note:If you modify the system variable then you need to restart the system.

Answer (score 1):

There is this file kafka-run-class.bat which gets referenced in most of the kafka scripts. It sets the JAVA parameter depending on the JAVA_HOME variable mentioned below: 
set JAVA="%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java"

We need to modify this since JAVA_HOME already contains path until 'bin'. So now Kafka tries to append an extra bin directory to the path. We need to alter this as mentioned below:
set JAVA="%JAVA_HOME%/java"

Now on starting the zookeeper again in a fresh command prompt the error is gone and the zookeeper starts fine.